# How to debug remote Java application through nginx reverse proxy

Tags: java, nginx, remote-debugging, nginx-reverse-proxy, jdwp

I need to debug a remote java application running behind an nginx reverse proxy.
I get the following error:

> Failed to attach to remote debuggee VM. Reason: java.io.IOException: Received invalid handshake

What should be the right nginx configuration to achieve this?

I have successfully attached vscode java debugger to the remote java application by targeting the app's host directly.

Resolver is 127.0.0.11 because I'm using nginx docker image.

My nginx config file `app.xyz.com.conf` in conf.d:

```
server {
    listen 1043;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    server_name app.xyz.com;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    location / {
        proxy_buffer_size 8k;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        set $upstream "http://java-app:1043";
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should declare tcp port instead http for debug java application.